# Your Box service has been temporarily disabled

Tags: php, api, box

I was using box API. But now on login i am getting a message like

**Your Box service has been temporarily disabled**

Can anyone tell why my account suspended?
Any help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks,
M.

Comment: I'd ask the box support.

Comment: Mr. @Gerald Schneider, I have already wrote to support. I asked here because i think someone might have faced this problem. for that you gave me negative you could have replied me in a gentle way. Thats great.. salute you sir.. by the way thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author would be the first point of contact you should go to, as there's no information anyone on here would be able to give you.

https://developers.box.com/help/